# MVC 5 Adding Image as Claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity, claims

As title says, can I do this?  Here is what I tried:

```
private static string GetImage(this IIdentity identity)
{
    var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity) identity).FindFirst("Image");
    return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
}

public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Image", System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Image)));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Now the problem that I am finding is that inside GetImage method, the return value is namespace of Image field.  It doesn't actually return the value.  I assume this is because inside FindFirst method it does a .ToString() prior to returning me the values, which would explain why it gets the type.  My database has the value and I can access the image via user property, but I was wondering if I can add it to the claim instead, is there a way?